# Android Opencv Perspective Transformation not working as expected

Tags: android, opencv

I'm working with perspective transformation in opencv for android for a personal project. 
The thing I'd like to do is to acquire a document like CamScanner does.
For this I import a picture and let the user set the four transformation points needed. 
Everything works, except for the fact that the transformation seems to be applied to different points or something like  that. I need some fresh eyes  to point me to the right direction.

Note that `myHandle` is a custom class, its only interesting properties in this context are that they are points with `x` and `y` coordinates and `getX()` and `getY()` are its getters for the coordinates.
Here's my function for the transformation:

```
public Bitmap addrizzone(Bitmap image, ArrayList<myHandle> sourcePoints){
        // sourcePoints are  expected  to be clockwise ordered
        // [top_left,top_right,bottom_right,bottom_left]
        // getting the size of the output image
        double dst_width = Math.max(sourcePoints.get(0).distanceFrom(sourcePoints.get(1)),sourcePoints.get(3).distanceFrom(sourcePoints.get(2)));
        double dst_height = Math.max(sourcePoints.get(0).distanceFrom(sourcePoints.get(3)),sourcePoints.get(1).distanceFrom(sourcePoints.get(2)));

        //determining point sets to get the transformation matrix
        List<org.opencv.core.Point> srcPts = new ArrayList<org.opencv.core.Point>();
        for (myHandle ball : sourcePoints) {
            srcPts.add(new org.opencv.core.Point((ball.getX()),ball.getY()));
        }

        List<org.opencv.core.Point> dstPoints= new ArrayList<org.opencv.core.Point>();
        dstPoints.add(new org.opencv.core.Point(0,0));
        dstPoints.add(new org.opencv.core.Point(dst_width-1,0));
        dstPoints.add(new org.opencv.core.Point(dst_width-1,dst_height-1));
        dstPoints.add(new org.opencv.core.Point(0,dst_height));

        Mat srcMat = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(srcPts);
        Mat dstMat = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dstPoints);

        //getting the transformation matrix
        Mat perspectiveTransformation = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(srcMat,dstMat);

        //getting the input matrix from the given bitmap
        Mat inputMat = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);

        Utils.bitmapToMat(image,inputMat);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(inputMat,inputMat,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        //getting the output matrix with the previously determined sizes
        Mat outputMat = new Mat((int) dst_height,(int) dst_width,CvType.CV_8UC1);

        //applying the transformation
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat,outputMat,perspectiveTransformation,new Size(dst_width,dst_height));

        //creating the output bitmap
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)dst_width,(int)dst_height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        //Mat to Bitmap
        Imgproc.cvtColor(outputMat,outputMat,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
        Utils.matToBitmap(outputMat,outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

Some example screenshots:
[image: User determined the points]

User determined the points
[image: Transformation is not as expected]

Transformation is not as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I didn't map the touch coordinates into image coordinates, they are different.
here's the updated and working code for defining the right dimensions:

```
for (myHandle ball : sourcePoints) {

            srcPts.add(new Point((ball.getX()*image.getWidth() / screenWidth),ball.getY()*image.getHeight()/screenHeight));
        }

        double dst_width = Math.max(distance(srcPts.get(0),srcPts.get(1)),
                distance(srcPts.get(2),srcPts.get(3)));

        double dst_height = Math.max(distance(srcPts.get(0),srcPts.get(3)),
                distance(srcPts.get(1),srcPts.get(2)));
```

Where `distance` is:

```
private double distance(Point p1, Point p2){
    return Math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x) + (p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y));
}
```